# UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

receive this error automatically:

> UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging ::
>   UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache
>   does not have 46dc9eae-db02-4ee1-9aa5-2ac64bc2869e

after checking few articles, i have verified that the distributed cache account is given full control access to the user profile sync

still the error pops up, can anybody suggest on this?
Thank you

Comment: do you have any issue in the farm i.e feed not working?

Comment: Does the account you are using to execute your code have permission to use the User Profile Service?

Comment: Yes, it has Full control permission for the user profile service
But want to make note , this account id not the service account for distributed cache service,

Comment: as i have read in various articles that add the account which is used to run the distributed cache as full control access to run the UPS service, that account and the account which is used to execute the code are different service accounts, but both have full access to the UPS service

Comment: even tried restarting the appfabric service, no luck...